# User Removed from Doman and Drivers Reset Every Day

Tags: windows-10, group-policy

Two weeks ago I set up a laptop for one of the users in our organization. I added the machine to the domain and added him to the local admin group. I also found a conflicting driver for the machine's DVD drive in the device manager (code 19). I uninstalled the driver and added the user to the local admin group without issue.

However two days later the user came back to me as he was having issues installing software, and couldn't find the disk on his machine because the conflicting driver error had returned. Every other day or so I end up having to re-add him to the local admin group and uninstalling the bad driver.

We don't have any GPO that would be causing this. Machine is a Lenovo Thinkpad from 2013 or therabouts. Any idea on what might be causing this?

Comment: Did yo mean the user account remove from domain user group & local Admin group automatically? Any clue in the event viewer? Was the computer "domain joined" status keeping?

Comment: The user was removed from the local administrator group. They were not altered on the domain. The computer remains as a domain machine. Nothing glaringly obvious in the event viewer, but I'll go through the motions today and have him check in once it resets again.

Comment: when an user was remove from local admin group, there will be event log recorded as this: https://1drv.ms/i/s!Avq27-O7I1GRgxHOqT_MXF92RR2A